# Respuesta de endPoint se regresa con doble valor usando slim framework

Tags: php, pdo, rest, slim

¡Buenas!

Tengo el siguiente endPoint que me regresa el siguiente resultado.
¿Por que regresa repetidos los valores?

Realmente no tengo idea en qué momento se asignan los parámetros de la respuesta que aparecen enumerados de 0 al 4, yo esperaba solamente los parámetros con palabras.

La ruta funciona, me permite loguearme bien, pero no entiendo de donde vienen esos valores.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda de antemano.

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app -> post('/api/login', function(Request $request, Response $response){

  $nombre = $request -> getParam('Nombre');
  $password = $request -> getParam('Contrasena');
  $contrasena = md5(base64_encode($password));

      try{
        $db = new db();
        $db = $db -> conectar();

        $consulta = "SELECT usuario.IdUsuario, usuario.Nombre, usuario.FkCat_TipoUsuario,
        usuario.FkCat_Estatus_Usuario, cat_tipousuario.TipoUsuario
        FROM usuario
        INNER JOIN cat_tipousuario on usuario.FkCat_TipoUsuario = cat_tipousuario.IdTipoUsuario
        WHERE usuario.Nombre = :Nombre
        AND usuario.Contrasena = :Contrasena";

        $auth = $db->prepare($consulta);

        $auth->bindParam(':Nombre', $nombre);
        $auth->bindParam(':Contrasena', $contrasena);
        $auth->execute();
        $rows=$auth->rowCount();

        if($rows > 0){
            $responseData['status'] = 1;
          $responseData['response'] = $auth->fetchAll();
            // $responseData['response'] = $auth->fetchAll();
        }else{
            $responseData['status'] = 0;
            $responseData['msg'] = 'Usuario o contraseña incorrectos.';
        }

        return $this->response->withJson($responseData, 200);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e -> getMessage().'}';
    }

});

?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, has un `var_dump` de `$this->response->withJson($responseData, 200);` o de tu variable `$responseData` antes de hacer el return y verifica que tenga la estructura que esperas del lado cliente. Es lo primero a revisar. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El resultado se debe a que al hacer [`$auth->fetchAll()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php) el `fetch_style` por defecto es `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` el cual:

> Devuelve un array indexado tanto por nombre de columna, como numéricamente con índice de base 0 tal como fue devuelto en el conjunto de resultados.

### Solución:

Podrías usar [`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) que:

> Devuelve un array indexado por los nombres de las columnas del conjunto de resultados.

#### Ejemplo:

```
//...
$responseData['status'] = 1;
$responseData['response'] = $auth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//...
```

Comment: Gracias Marcos, justo eso era, lo habia olvidado por completo.